# How can I generate the cartesian product of some vectors, whose number is given at runtime in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, cartesian-product

If I had n vectors I could do something like:

```
for(auto& i : v1) {
    for(auto& j: v2) {
       ...
           for(auto& z: vn){
                 f(i,j,k,...,z)
           }
     }
}
```

but since the vectors over which compute the cartesian product are not known until the user provides some inputs at runtime, I don't know how could I compute the product.

I tried looking up something in the  library but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: If you only know the number of vectors at run time, then you can't (or shouldn't) be using variables. Do you have a `vector<vector<>>` or something else? That's important to figure out the appropriate solution.

Comment: yes, I have a `vector<vector<int>>`